# Position of the latest version in r

Tags: r

I have 5 variables. I want to Create one variable which has the latest version.

For Example.

```
Version10 Version 8 Version9 Version 5 version1  expected Output
  1         1          0         0        0      Version10
  0        0            1       1        0       Version9
  0          1         1        1         1      Version8
  0          0          0        0        1       version1
```

I tried with following syntax but getting an error.

df<-data.frame(cbind(Version10,Version9,Version8,Version5,Version1))

```
for (i in 1:5) {
if (maxvalue==df(I) {
maxvar<-i
maxcount<-maxcount+1 }
```

Please suggest.

Thanks
Tanuvi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use `max.col` to find the index of the max value in each row, if there are multiple max values, then use the `ties.method = "first"`. subset the column names based on the index and create a new column

```
df1$expectedOutput <- names(df1)[max.col(df1, "first")]
df1$expectedOutput
#[1] "Version10" "Version9"  "Version8"  "Version1"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Version10 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Version8 = c(1L, 
 0L, 1L, 0L), Version9 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Version5 = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L), Version1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Version10", 
"Version8", "Version9", "Version5", "Version1"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. This is very useful. one more query..If all the versions are zero it is, considering the first variable, actually it should be zero. Is there any option for that?

Comment: @Tanuvi  In that case, use `rowSums` to create NA for those elements i.e. `names(df1)[max.col(df1, "first") * NA^(rowSums(df1!=0)==0)]` or either index it first `i1 <- rowSums(df1!=0) >0; df1$expectedOutput <- NA; df1$expectedOutput[i1] <- names(df1)[max.col(df1[i1,], "first")]`

Answer (score -1):

You are missing something in row 3, I guess the expected outcome should be version 9 her instead of v8.

Secondly, as you are defining string data frame so use the quotation around versions. Try something this with correct logic.

```
df<data.frame(cbind('Version10','Version9','Version8','Version5','Version1'))
```